# Copy data from different workbook and paste it to specific sheets on a report workbook

Tags: excel, vba

Currently i am new on studying VBA for reporting and im still learning from it. moving on, may i ask a help on this one? :), my scenario is this.

- i have data on 20 workbooks (POLY, BAYO, PROPO, TIPAS, CITRO....etc) with sheet name (Sheet1)
- i have a single workbook for summary with many sheets, its sheet name is based on 20 workbook file name but not in alphabetical order. (Sheet name = CITRO, BAYO, PROPO, POLY, TIPAS....etc)
- i want to copy the data on each workbook and paste it to their respective sheet name based on file name and specific cell ("B2:F2")
- is it doable?

here's the code im trying to work on, the problem is, it is creating its own sheet instead of pasting it to my desire sheet.

---

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim SourceBook As Workbook   
Dim CurrentBook As Workbook

application.screenupdating = false
Set CurrentBook = ThisWorkbook

Set SourceBook = Workbooks.Open("C:\CITRO.xlsx")
SourceBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:F2").Copy Destination:=CurrentBook.Sheets("CITRO").Range("R2:V2")

Set SourceBook = Workbooks.Open("C:\BAYO.xlsx")
SourceBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:F2").Copy Destination:=CurrentBook.Sheets("BAYO").Range("R2:V2")

Set SourceBook = Workbooks.Open("C:\PROPO.xlsx")
SourceBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:F2").Copy Destination:=CurrentBook.Sheets("PROPO").Range("R2:V2")

MsgBox "Completed"
Application.Workbooks("CITRO").Close
Application.Workbooks("BAYO").Close
Application.Workbooks("PROPO").Close
'SourceBook.Close
'Set SourceBook = Nothing
'Set CurrentBook = Nothing

'ThisWorkbook.Activate
'Application.Worksheets("Summary").Activate
'Application.Worksheets("Summary").Range("B2:F2").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Because `SourceBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Copy` copies the entire sheet. You need to copy only a range `SourceBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B10").Copy Destination:=CurrentBook.Sheets("Summary").Range("A1")` ‹~~ all in one line. Adjust the range addresses to your need.

Comment: thanks for the input -Peh, for now thats the code i made, since im not yet familiar with loops, (someone told me). and i basically do manual static codes for it, also i remove sourcebook.close and replaced with application.workbooks("Sheets").close the reason is i dont know why it remains open the data source workbook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to close the `SourceBook` before opening a new one with `SourceBook.Close SaveChanges:=False`

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim SourceBook As Workbook   
    Dim CurrentBook As Workbook

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'don't forget to activate it in the end
    Set CurrentBook = ThisWorkbook

    Set SourceBook = Workbooks.Open("C:\CITRO.xlsx")
    SourceBook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:F2").Copy Destination:=CurrentBook.Worksheets("CITRO").Range("R2:V2")
    SourceBook.Close SaveChanges:=False

    Set SourceBook = Workbooks.Open("C:\BAYO.xlsx")
    SourceBook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:F2").Copy Destination:=CurrentBook.Worksheets("BAYO").Range("R2:V2")
    SourceBook.Close SaveChanges:=False

    Set SourceBook = Workbooks.Open("C:\PROPO.xlsx")
    SourceBook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:F2").Copy Destination:=CurrentBook.Worksheets("PROPO").Range("R2:V2")
    SourceBook.Close SaveChanges:=False

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True        
    MsgBox "Completed"
End Sub
```

---

Alternatively you can use a procedure to shorten it:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()        
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'don't forget to activate it in the end

    CopyIntoThisWorkbook "C:\CITRO.xlsx", "CITRO"
    CopyIntoThisWorkbook "C:\BAYO.xlsx", "BAYO"
    CopyIntoThisWorkbook "C:\PROPO.xlsx", "PROPO"

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True        
    MsgBox "Completed"
End Sub


Private Sub CopyIntoThisWorkbook(ByVal SourceFileName As String, ByVal DestinationSheetName As Range)
    Dim SourceBook As Workbook
    Set SourceBook = Workbooks.Open(SourceFileName)
    SourceBook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:F2").Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(DestinationSheetName).Range("R2:V2")
    SourceBook.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub
```

---

And if the sheet name `CITRO` is **always** the filename `CITRO.xlsx` then you can even use an array with a loop:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()        
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'don't forget to activate it in the end
    Dim SheetNameList() As Variant
    SheetNameList = Array("CITRO", "BAYO", "PROPO") 'easily extendable

    Dim SheetName As Variant
    For Each SheetName In SheetNameList
        CopyIntoThisWorkbook SheetName
    Next SheetName

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True        
    MsgBox "Completed"
End Sub


Private Sub CopyIntoThisWorkbook(ByVal DestinationSheetName As String)
    Dim SourceBook As Workbook
    Set SourceBook = Workbooks.Open("C:\" & DestinationSheetName & ".xlsx")
    SourceBook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:F2").Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(DestinationSheetName).Range("R2:V2")
    SourceBook.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: wonderful. i will study on loop now so that i can minimize the line of codes instead of doing 20 lines for that :)). thank you peh

Comment: @JNS Have a look at my answer again.

Comment: wonderful, im not yet ready to fully understand this, but i will try my best to study that code. since im actually im a beginner, honestly. 
late reply due to celebration of my birthday. cheers!